# Подключение нескольких клиентов по udp

Tags: c, разработка-игр, udp

Имеется сервер, который постоянно принимает пакеты от клиента и отправляет их обратно. Необходимо, чтобы тоже самое происходило с несколькими клиентами.
Понимаю примерную концепцию, что нужно как-то организовать структуру сокетов и в цикле их перебирать, но ничего толкового у меня не вышло.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    int n;
    unsigned int clilen; 
    char line[1000];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(51000);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror(NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, 
    sizeof(servaddr)) < 0){
        perror(NULL);
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1) {
        clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
        if((n = recvfrom(sockfd, line, 999,
                         0,(struct sockaddr *)
                         &cliaddr, &clilen)) < 0){
            perror(NULL);
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("%s\n", line);
        if(sendto(sockfd, line, strlen(line),
                  0,(struct sockaddr *)
                  &cliaddr, clilen) < 0){
            perror(NULL);
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Типовый шаблон для UDP сервера выглядит так:

```
int listener; // Слушающий сокет сервера;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
size_t len;

listener = socket(...SOCK_DGRAM...);
servaddr = ...; // Задаём свой адрес/порт
bind(listener, servaddr); // В сокете задаём его адрес
while (1) {
    len = recvfrom(listener,... &cliaddr,...); // Ждём прихода запроса
    // Формируем ответ
    sendto(listener, cliaddr); // Отправляем ответ
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, Вы его реализовали совершенно правильно. А вот Ваш вопрос про:

> Необходимо, чтобы тоже самое происходило с несколькими клиентами.

выглядит не совсем понятно. А в чём собственно проблема? Пришёл запрос от одного клиента - прочитали, обработали, отправили ответ. Пришёл запрос от другого клиента. Прочитали, обработали, отправили ответ. Обратите внимание: мы используем только один(!) сокет - слушающий. И ничегов в нём не  меням. Зачем Вам:

> как-то организовать структуру сокетов и в цикле их перебирать,

Каких сокетов?! Ещё раз: сокет только один. Если Вы хотите обрабатывать запросы от клиентов параллельно, ну пожалуйста - внутри цикла создавайте нитку по приходу каждого запроса и передавайте ей адрес клиента и буфер запроса от него.  Эта нитка обработает запрос, отправит ответ и сама закроется. Всё...